# Issue overwriting cookie in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, object, cookies

Anytime I attempt to retrieve this cookie back after they go through our payments gateway (which redirects to a different domain, and then takes the user back to our page) the cookie does NOT persist :(

It acts like it didn't load the object from the cookie at all.

Here's the code I'm using to store/restore the cookie:

```
public static string Store(EIN ein)
    {
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test123")
        {
            // Set the expiry date of the cookie to 15 years
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(15)
        };
        Stream myStream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            // Create a binary formatter and serialize the
            // myClass into the memorystream
            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(myStream, ein);
            // Go to the beginning of the stream and
            // fill a byte array with the contents of the
            // memory stream
            myStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[myStream.Length];
            myStream.Read(buffer, 0, (int)myStream.Length);
            // Store the buffer as a base64 string in the cookie
            cookie.Value = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            cookie.Domain = "url.com";
            // Add the cookie to the current http context

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        }
        finally
        {
            // ... and remember to close the stream
            myStream.Close();
        }

        return cookie.Path;
    }

    public static EIN Restore()
    {
        // Always remember to check that the cookie is not empty
        HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["test123"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
            // Convert the base64 string into a byte array
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cookie.Value);
            // Create a memory stream from the byte array
            Stream myStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
            try
            {
                // Create a binary formatter and deserialize the
                // contents of the memory stream into MyClass
                IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
                EIN streamedClass = (EIN)formatter.Deserialize(myStream);
                return streamedClass;
            }
            finally
            {
                // ... and as always, close the stream
                myStream.Close();
            }
        }
        return new EIN();
    }
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

When explicitly setting the domain of a cookie, the domain should start with a leading dot.  Try setting the domain to `.url.com` and see whether that works.

From [RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt):

```
Domain=domain
   Optional.  The Domain attribute specifies the domain for which the
   cookie is valid.  An explicitly specified domain must always start
   with a dot.
```

Comment: Made the change, till no luck :(

Comment: OK, try removing your try { } ... maybe an exception is being silently raised an discarded before the cookie is actually set. Use your browser's dev tools to view the headers ... is the cookie actually being set?